# How to specify union value at construction

Tags: python, union, ctypes

I am trying to pass an array of unions via ctypes to my C++ DLL and I am fairly new to Python. Is there a shorthand way of constructing them, for example:

```
class MyValue(Union):
  _fields_ = [
    ("ftNone"  , c_void_p),
    ("ftString", c_char_p),
    ("ftInt"   , c_int   ),
    ("ftBigInt", c_long  ),
    ("ftFloat" , c_char_p)
  ]
MyValues = MyValue * 20

CMethod(MyValues(
 ('ftInt'    = 12),
 ('ftString' = 'testing')
))
```

Or is there a better way of doing this?. I basically want to pass an array of mixed types to my DLL.

Comment: @eryksun: Not for the use case I am implementing this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ctypes array is initialized with positional arguments. An initial value can be a ctypes data object, a Python object compatible with a simple data type (for an array of simple types such as `c_int * 20`), or a tuple of positional arguments used to create a temporary instance of the array's data type to be copied (`memcpy`) into the array.

Since you need a keyword argument to select the proper converter, you'll have to either call `MyValue` to manually create the temporary instance, or call `setattr` on each item of an unitialized array. For the former, you can use a generator expression combined with `*` and `**` unpacking (see the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)):

```
values = [
    ('ftInt', 12),
    ('ftString', 'testing'),
]

arr = MyValues(*(MyValue(**{k: v}) for k, v in values))
```

And here's an alternative using [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to update the array in a loop:

```
arr = MyValues()
for item, value in zip(arr, values):
    setattr(item, *value) # note the * unpacking
```

---

It would be nice to add support for a keyword argument dict in [`_PyCData_set`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#l2850) (Modules/ctypes/_ctypes.c).